# SubSonic InlineQuery returning wrong results with ExecuteAsCollection

Tags: subsonic, executereader

Using SubSonic 2.2, I have this query:

```
string q = @"SELECT Media.Id, Media.Title FROM Media WHERE Media.UserId = 7"
DAL.MediumCollection matches = new InlineQuery().ExecuteAsCollection<DAL.MediumCollection>(q).Load();
```

Looping through "matches" results in every single entry in the "Media" table.

However, when I do this:

```
IDataReader reader = new InlineQuery().ExecuteReader(q);
```

It returns the correct rows. Why is ExecuteAsCollection returning something completely different from ExecuteReader? Has anyone else experience this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're calling .Load(). That's overwriting your original query.

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteAsCollection() should do it.

When you call the Load() method it's just like doing `new DAL.MediumCollection().Load()` that returns all the data in the table.